# Calling google api explorer methods from a web application (java/jsp) endpoint

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I want to call my method from my google explorer api. I have a web application client (java/jsp) with endpoint. My method :

```
  // Method to fetch result from datastore with email and date param
  @ApiMethod(name = "greetings.getDataNewSeance", httpMethod = "get")
  public List getDataInStore(@Named("Email") String email, @Named("Date") String date) {

    List<String> listNewSeance = new ArrayList<String>();

    Query q = new Query("NewSeance");
    q.addFilter("Email", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, email);
    q.addFilter("Date", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, date);

    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

    for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()) 
    {
    listNewSeance.add((String)entity.getProperty("Email"));
    listNewSeance.add((String)entity.getProperty("Date"));
    listNewSeance.add((String)entity.getProperty("Calories"));
    listNewSeance.add((String)entity.getProperty("Distance"));
    listNewSeance.add((String)entity.getProperty("MeterMin"));
    listNewSeance.add((String)entity.getProperty("Time"));
    }

    return listNewSeance;

    }
```

**Q1 :**
Does I have to call with javascript like in this tutorial [Using Endpoints in a JavaScript Client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js)

or can I do this in java/jsp like pretty much in an android client and how?

**Q2 :**
Does my method "getDataNewSeance()" is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints is a great way to accelerate backend services development. It allows you to easily publish a service and also facilitates accessing these services using different technologies such as Android or iOS apps. Anyway, it still follows some standards such as REST/JSON. That said, let me try to answer our questions:

Q1: You don't HAVE to use the javascript libs to access the service. You can call the service using pretty much any client you want. Just make REST calls to your service.

Q2: I would change a couple of things... The most important change I think you should consider is to change your result data structure. You are return a list of Strings that could be email, date, calories and so on. You could create a POJO with all these attributes and serialize that POJO to a JSON using Jackson or Gson, for example. Your result would be a JSON with several entries. In a real application, you might also want to create a DAO to encapsulate the data access to Datastore, instead of putting this code inside the API layer. I like to keep the API layer as thin as possible.

Good luck!